# A simple geometric distribution word problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, algorithms

I am stuck with what should be a simple probability problem.

There is an algorithm for choosing advertisements from $m$ pages. The $i$th page has $n(i)$ advertisements, with $n(i)$ less than some number $n$.

Here is how the algorithm works:

- Choose a random page from $m$ pages
- Accept that page with probability $n(i)/n$
- If accepted, choose an ad from those on the page
- Else repeat the loop

The question: **What is the expected number of iterations taken by the algorithm?**

This (I think) reduces to a geometric distribution with mean $1/p$ where $p$ is the probability of accepting an ad on any particular iteration.

I have verified that the probability of accepting any of the $m$ pages (and therefore accepting an advertisement) is $p = \bar{n}/n$, where $ \bar{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{m}n(i)/m$.

If the above is correct, then the expected number of iterations should be $n/\bar{n}$.

However, my book (Ross) tells me the solution is $n\sqrt{n}$.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made no mistake; the book's answer is wrong (answer keys can have errors).

For example, suppose every page has the same number, $k\;$say, of advertisements, where $0 < k \le n$.

Then if $e$ is the expected number of iterations, we get
$$
e
=
\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
{\cdot\,}
1
+
\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)
{\cdot\,}
(1+e)
$$
which yields $e={\large{\frac{n}{k}}}$, not $e=n\sqrt{n}$.

**Note:**$\;$The book's answer $n\sqrt{n}$ typographically resembles $n/\bar{n}$, so it's possibly an error by the publisher, not the author.

Comment: Thank you for the satisfying typographical explanation. I checked answer keys for two different editions, but I guess some errors take a while to be reported!